# Exact (!) relation between Martingale Problem, SDEs and Markov processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

I am currently trying to understand the big picture/connections of Martingale Problem, Fokker-Planck-equations (although, until now, I have mostly kept these out of my considerations), SDEs and Markov processes. Maybe this long post is valuable for some people trying to get into this area and the connections, as I will try to point out as many connections and relations as possible. But I have some questions myself. Ok, here we go. The way I think about these items (on a large scale) is (roughly) as follows:
(I only consider continuous Markov processes with values in $\mathbb{R}^d$)

The Markov process is really at the center of the attention - it is the ultimate object of desire, whereas the other ones are rather auxiliary tools for the understanding of it (I am very aware that these fields - in particular SDEs and, emerging from it, SPDEs have a large and rich theory of its own, which I am familiar with to a decent degree - but here I am really putting the Markov process in the heart of everything).

Assume we are in the lucky situation that we know the transition function/semigroup of the Markov Process or the family of its laws, usually called $(\mathbb{P}_x)_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}$ AND we also know the generator. Then we have everything we could ask for and the corresponding Martingale problem or the corresponding SDE are not needed. Is this essentially correct?

Now of course one hardly ever has all these information at hand. A much more common situation is/seems to be (I have not witnessed this myself, but read it several times) that one only knows the generator, which is of the form
$$L(x) = \frac{1}{2}a_{ij}(x)\partial_i\partial_j+b_i(x)\partial_i.$$Further, one might not even know whether the given operator generates a Markovian semigroup, i.e. a Markov process. Intuively, $L$ describes the drift (via $b$) and the variance/fluctuation (via $a$) of the particle governed by the Markov law under consideration when it sits at position $x$ (for simplicity, let's stick to the time-homogeneous case).

Well, knowing only the generator may not be sufficient for a thorough understanding of the processes behaviour - hence one turns to the corresponding SDE and/or the Martingale problem (as I said, I omit the FP-eq. for now) for more information.

$\textbf{SDE}:$ The corresponding stochastic differential equation reads $dX_t = b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t$, where (if existing!) $\sigma\sigma^T = a$ is a (possibly non-unique) square root of $a$ and $B$ is a Brownian motion. It is well-known that if the coefficients of the SDE are suffiecently good to admit a unique strong solution, then this solution is a Markov process with $L$ as its generator. Then one may analyze this solution by means of SDE-/stochastic analysis techniques to obtain interesting properties.

However, the drawback of this approach lies in (at least) two points: First, obviously our coefficients might not be good enough, i.e. they might not be Lipschitz or similar. Then we don't have uniqueness and do not obtain the Markov property (right?). Secondly, the diffusion matrix $a$ may not have have square root $\sigma$ with such nice properties, even if $a$ itself enjoys good properties (I know there are some conditions under which one can transfer properties of $a$ to its square root. But it is not always the case). Hence it is natural to look for another approach. This is why Stroock\Varadhan introduced the

$\textbf{Martingale Problem}:$ First of all it is quite natural to study it, because by Ito-formula every solution to an SDE (in the sense of its law) as above solves the corresponding martingale problem ($\textit{corresponding}$ means: The coefficients of the martingale problem are $b$ and a = $\sigma\sigma^T$). Now appparently I can write down the martingale problem in a meaningful way without any assumptions on the coefficients but measurability - an advantage compared to the SDE-apporach! Also, a priori I do not have to care about a square root of $a$ with good properties. Nice!

$\textbf{BUT}$, and now comes my actual main question, is the martingale problem-apporach in the end really more general? I KNOW that the two approaches are equivalent if I know that my $a$ has a sufficiently nice square root. So for justification, there should be a real benefit for the martingale problem-apporach in the case where $a$ or its square root(s) are not so nice. Hence let us assume I have coefficients $a$ and $b$, which are not good enough for the SDE-approach. What then? The martingale problem-approach is only beneficial, if I know that it is well-posed, for then the existence of a Markov process (the $\mathbb{P}_x$ are the unique solutions to the martingale problem in this case) with the given generator follows (else you may still be able to make a Markovian selection, c.f. Chapter 12 S.\V., but I dont think you can get many information out of this selection, can you?)

So, to wrap it up: Is, and if yes in what precise sense, the martingale problem apporach in the end really strictly better than the SDE-approach? I feel I really need to get this straight to arrange a better structure/hierarchy in my head.

I am grateful for any reasonable comment on this - an answer to any of my side question or just further discussion!

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this paper](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~kurtz/papers/mgsde.pdf); in particular Theorem 1.1 and Corollary 1.3

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know this paper, it does state a precise equivalence for both existence and uniqueness between martingale problem and SDE. But isn't the author a little imprecise when he introduces the SDE and the corresponding generator - to me it seems that he STARTS with the coefficients of the SDE, i.e. in particular with $\sigma$, and then (without saying so) defines\assumes $(a_{ij})$ to be the square of $\sigma$. In this situation, both $a$ and $\sigma$ are obviously good enough to obtain the mentioned equivalences. This way, the author does not treat my main question, does he?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but I don't see that Kurtz assumes in his paper that the square root is unique. If $a(x)$ is positive semidefinite, then it does have a square root $\sigma(x)$. Assuming that we can choose $\sigma(x)$ such that $x \mapsto \sigma(x)$ is measurable, then we can apply Kurtz' result for $a$ and $\sigma$, and we will get equivalence of the two notions, right?

Comment: I agree. It is not the possible non-uniqueness of the square root that bothers me. Maybe I'm stuck on a simple point, but is it always true that a square root exists? I came across lecture notes, which stated something like "$\textbf{assume}$ that there exists a square root. Then a martingale sol. can be expressed as a weak solution to the corresponding SDE"...But yes - now that I think about it, the square root certainly exists, right? Mh. Ok. Then we have the equivalence on the level of existence AND uniqueness. Pretty strong. So why do S./V. claim that the martingale approach is powerful?

Comment: We can only expect to associate a stochastic process with $L$ if $a(x)$ is positve semi-definite and, as I already mentioned, positive semi-definite matrices do have a square root (not necessarily unique). Regarding the powerfulness of martingale problems: From my (limited) point of view, the result by Kurtz (i.e. this strong link between martingale problems and solutions to SDEs) is actually one of **the** reasons to study martingale problems for 2nd order differential operators. It allows you transfer properties (existence + uniqueness) from one notion to the other.

Comment: Construcing weak solutions to SDEs directly (using the very definition) is pretty difficult (except from some particular cases, e.g. using Girsanov's theorem), and therefore the equivalence between martingale problems and SDEs is a really convient tool to construct weak solutions to SDEs. More generally, martingale problems can be considered for a larger class of operators $L$ and, hence, give way to the construction of a larger class of stochastic processes.

Comment: Concerning your first comment: I agree. And yes, the equivalence of ex.&uniqu. for martingale problem and SDE is convenient, no doubt. Concerning your last sentence: You mean that the martingale problem is meaningful for "any" operator $L$ which acts on a set of measurable functions - while on the contrary, you can obviously not consider "the SDE" for such a general operato. Ok, this clearly is another advantage. But as long as one only cares for the construction and analysis of Markov processes, the operator/generator will be of second order diff.-type, so this advantage is not present (?)

Comment: No, the generator of a Markov process is not necessarily of second order differential type... for instance for Lévy processes (which are a subclass of Markov processes) the generator is of the form $$Lf(x) = \sum_i b_i \partial_i f(x) +\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} \partial_{i,j} f(x) + \int_{y \neq 0} (f(x+y)-f(x)-y \nabla f(x) 1_{(0,1)}(|y|)) \, \nu(dy),$$ more generally, for Feller processes, the coefficients $b_i$, $a_{i,j}$ and $\nu$ may depend on the space variable $x$.

Comment: What bugged me is that in S./V. it sounds like they think of the mart. prob. as a method superior to those of SDEs and FP-eq. - and this not only since the martingale problem might be better to handle, but really from the perspective of its range of applicability. But I understand that the results by Kurtz neglect this point of view. But I guess I'm correct in my view that the martingale problem is a "natural" way to think about Markov processes, because starting from a reasonable intuitive picture (Levy's idea of Markovian movement), one arrives precisely at the mart. prob.-formulation (?)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "continuous Markov processes have generators of the form $L_t(x) = \frac{1}{2}a_{ij}(t,x)\partial_i\partial_j+b_i(t,x)\partial_i$" - is this correct?

Comment: , where $L$ is independent of $t$ if and only if the Markov process is time-homogeneous.

Comment: @saz, maybe this question is really stupid: Ok, for a pos. semidefinite diffusion $a$ we always have a square root $/sigma$. But, assuming $a$ to be measurable and bd., do we always know that we get a square root with these two properties? I guess boundedness is clear, since $||\sigma\sigma^T|| \leq ||\sigma||^2$, right? But can the measurability be a subtle problem? Further, am I correct in seeing another advantage in the martingale pr.-approach in the the following: In the end, ex. and uniqu. for SDE/Martingale pr. are equivalent - fine. But if I do NOT know a priori that I have...

Comment: ...uniqueness, then it might be hard/not practicable to check uniqueness for the SDE directly. Hence - due to the equivalence - I can turn to the martingale pr.-side and study uniqueness there. Of course this holds analogously for existence-questions.

Comment: Yes, that's what you typically do. Show existence/uniqueness for the MP and then get the existence/uniquess of the weak solution for SDE thanks to the equivalence of the two notions. Re your first question: If $a$ is continuous, then it can be shown that $\sigma$ can be chosen in a continuous way as well, see e.g. [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X97953269). If $a$ is only measurable (not nec. continuous), I'm not aware of such a result, but I'm really not an expert in this...