# Deriving SDE from generator of Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that $U$ is a Markov process. I was able to calculate it's generator which is

$$Gf(u)=-\lambda f'(u)+\frac{1}{2}\lambda f''(u)$$

Is it true, that $U$ satisfies the SDE

$$dU = -\lambda dt+\sqrt{\lambda}dB$$

for some Brownian motion $B$? Does there exist a theorem that applies to this situation?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Or is it maybe the other way around? Can I conclude from $dU=-\lambda dt + \sqrt{\lambda} dB$, that the generator of $U$ is $Gf$ as in the question?

Comment: If you want to infer from the generator to the SDE you've got to fix the domain of the generator first.

Comment: *Formally*, the relationship between generator and SDE is as simple as you wrote. To make this rigorous was a saga that kept a lot of the brightest people busy for the best part of the last century. The discussion in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126336/exact-relation-between-martingale-problem-sdes-and-markov-processes) gives a good taste.